# Restore Database "with replace" - is "with move" necessary?

Tags: sql-server, backup, restore

Database backup was created with files in location A
Database files then moved to location B using ALTER DATABASE MODIFY FILE

Now restoring the backup using WITH REPLACE created when files were in location A. Should the WITH MOVE option be specified with the new location? Or does WITH REPLACE imply using the current locations regardless of where they were when the backup was created?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have to specify WITH MOVE.

Comment: Here's the response I got on the MSDN forum:
"WITH REPLACE will use the current locations of the files for all files with matching logical names. It's most relevant when you're restoring a database to a second server (eg test or DR) where the file structure doesn't match exactly. On your target, if you set up a new shell database with the same logical file names as your source (different paths, different file sizes, different filenames even), you can do a simple RESTORE WITH REPLACE, and the database will restore to the shell's location."

Comment: Just a note, this only seems to work if the backups are from the same SQL version.  I was trying to use the same logical filenames on a SQL 2012 database from a SQL 2008 backup and it was failing and I had to issue the WITH MOVE statements.

Comment: @Brad the likely reason you had to use `WITH MOVE` is that the SQL 2008 backups were backed up with the SQL 2008 location subtree in their path. When back ups are made, they remember the FULL PATH of where their physical data files resided. You have to use `WITH MOVE` to OVERRIDE using the original physical files full path. SQL 2012 has a different install directory location from 2008, hence the need for the `WITH MOVE`. The only way to avoid that would be host all databases in a common directory (ie, "d:\DataFiles\").

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the Microsoft changed the behavior in SQL Server 2012 vs 2008.
If you back up a database with files on location A, and then files move to location B then, when you restore the database using "WITH REPLACE" and without "WITH MOVE", the restore succeeds in SQL 2005/2008 even if location A does not exist. After the restore, the database would still have the files on location B (as of before the restore).
However, the exactly same scenario with SQL 2012, the restore fails with the error that you need to use the "WITH MOVE" option.

Not sure if that was intended or not, since I have not found the change being documented by Microsoft...